# synchronized lock on socket object

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, synchronized

I have a below code in which I am using synchronized on a socket:

```
public boolean send(final long addr, final byte[] enc, final Socket socket) {
    ZMsg msg = new ZMsg();
    msg.add(enc);    

    // using the socket as its own lock while accessing it
    boolean sent;
    synchronized (socket) {
        sent = msg.send(socket);
    }
    msg.destroy();
    retryHolder.put(addr, enc);
    return sent;
}
```

I wanted to understand how this `synchronized` on a socket will work here? I have around 20 threads calling this `send` method concurrently and each time `Socket` can be different. We have around 60 sockets to choose from so all those 20 threads can pick any one socket from 60. It is possible, multiple threads can pick same socket to send data on or multiple threads can pick different socket everytime to send data on. Below are the scenarios I can think of:

- All 20 threads picking different socket each time to send data on as we have 60 sockets to work on. So how does `synchronized` on the socket will work in this scenario? Will it be fast or it will block for any threads?
- Out of 20 threads, some threads picking same socket to send data on randomly. So all those threads will wait for others before entering the `synchronized` block meaning each thread waiting for that socket to get freed up? So will it slow down anything?
- Any other case I missed?

Basically I am trying to figure out will there be any performance hit of using `socket` as the lock by using `synchronized` keyword for all the scenarios I can hit.

Comment: Usually the best practice is to handle synchronization at the `Socket` class level. Otherwise you will duplicate this logic everywhere you are sending stuff over Socket and can potentially forget to do it somewhere in your code. if you cannot change `Socket` class you can write a wrapper around it.

Answer (score 1):

This mechanism is in place to prevent different threads from sending data **to the same socket at the same time** and mucking up your data. Different threads using different sockets won't block, and although the act of synchronizing is not "free", it's negligible compared to sending data over the network.

Answer (score 0):

1. If each thread has different socket than other thread. Performance will not   be hampered. As no thread will be blocked to get lock on a socket.
2. Suppose If three threads have same socket. Only one will be allowed to send data on socket. Once it is finished lock will be release and next thread will get lock of the socket and start sending data and then 3rd thread and so on. So here there will be some performance impact. And as you mentioned threads are less in number as compared to sockets. I would advise to change implementation to assign the same socket to a thread only when all the sockets are already assigned to avoid any performance problems.

But yes if socket class is your own class and you can change the code. It is better to add synchronization on send method or preferably on all the methods, so that no other thread can use it if it does not have lock. And if you can not change it you can create wrapper class or proxy for Socket class, and make the methods in proxy class as synchronized.